# If запускается только 1 раз:

Tags: c++

If запускается только один раз, хоть должен 2 раза, код читает текст и если видит команду "print : " выводит текст к команде в файле test.sakura; Вот код:

text.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

char symbol;
string text;
fstream code;

int main()
{
    code.open("../test.sakura");
    while(code.get(symbol))
    {
        text += symbol;
        if(text == "print : ")
        {
            cout << "HELLO, IF!";
            do {
                code.get(symbol);
                if (symbol == ';')
                {
                    text = "";
                    cout << "\n";
                }
                else
                {
                    if (symbol != '"')
                    {
                        cout << symbol;
                    }
                }
            } while(symbol != ';');
        }
    }
}
```

test.sakura:

```
print : "alloha";
print : "hello!";
```

Для теста как только text = "print : " выводит "HELLO, IF!";
но производится только 1 раз, хоть "print : " есть 2

Вот что выводит:

```
HELLO, IF!alloha
```

а должно:

```
HELLO, IF!alloha
HELLO, IF!hello!
```

Comment: А вы перевод строки (ну, `\n`) не считаете за символ?...

Comment: Harry from Kiev я кажется понял про что вы, и сделал в test.sakura следущее: print : "alloha";print : "hello!";(всё в одну строку) и всё заработало, но мне хотелось бы сделать чтобы не учитывался перенос строки, можно как-то?

Comment: Harry from Kiev я немного изменил код, и сделал проверку если символ не равно "\n": text += symbol; и всё заработало, спасибо большое!